# OS error occurs when running DeepFace.stream()

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, deepface

I am completely new to deepface and I recently faced an error when running DeepFace.stream(). I tried to reinstall deepface, keras and h5py packages but the problem still occurs. Any solutions for this?

This is what I ran:

```
from deepface import DeepFace 
DeepFace.stream(db_path="dataset")
```

This is the error:

```
  File —\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonWython310\lib\site-packages\h5pyChl\files.py:220, in make_fic(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
     218 if swmr and swmr_support:
     219     flags |= h5f.ACC_SUMR_READ
 --> 220     fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=faal)
     221 elif mode == 'r+':
     222     fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl) 
 File h5pyCobjects.pyx:54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
 File h5py\_objects.pyx:55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
 File h5py\h5f.pyx:106, in h5py.h5f.open() 
    
  OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 55316580, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 580085408)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Where did your dataset come from?  The implication here is that the file was written to while it was being read.  It expects the end of file to be at 580MB, but the end is actually at 55MB.

Comment: And as a side note, I tried to fix your formatting, but there were some strange translation errors, as if you used an OCR app to convert to text, instead of cutting-and-pasting.  This might not match your code exactly.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. Inside the "dataset" folder, I used 7 jpg images containing some facial expressions. That's all.

Comment: Also, I ran the code in jupyter notebook and also in PyCharm IDE under the M1 macOS environment.